Cordova build for android is not working, although requirements are validated
Log after running build:
Console Log
Cordova Requirements verbose:
C:\MatrixCalc>cordova requirements android --verbose
Loaded API for android project C:\MatrixCalc\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-34,android-33
Gradle: installed C:\Gradle\gradle-7.4.2\bin\gradle.BAT
I tried to create a cordova mobile app. When I attempted to use "cordova build android" I got this error. The requirements are all met, environment variables for gradle and java are correct. Then what is going on with this?

You need to upgrade to Java 11

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
